# Restrict Field from other Children

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a created one Field on contact which is having checkbox data type name as "In use".
I have a requirement like

1.One Contact can only be active at one place at a time. So we want to restrict the "In Use" field from being active if it is currently active on another Contact for the same account.

Comment: You can create a trigger on contact for that kind of validation.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below trigger

```
trigger validate on Contact(before insert){
    SET<String> ids = new SET<String>();
        for(contact c : trigger.new){
            ids.add(c.AccountId);
        } 
        List<AggregateResult> tempAggr = [SELECT AccountId acc FROM Contact WHERE inUse__c= true AND Accontid IN : ids GROUP BY AccountId];

        Set<String> inUseset = new Set<String>();
        for(AggregateResult rs : tempAggr){
            inUseSet.add(String.valueOf(rs.get('acc')));
        }

        for(contact c : trigger.new){
            if(inUseSet.contains(c.AccountId)){
                c.inUse__c = false;
            }
            else{
                c.inUse__c = true;
                inUseSet.add(c.AccountId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: GROUP BY Account or AccounID??

Comment: There is slight Problem in this code when i checked in use for another child of same parent it will show me error this is good but when i unchecked it and then save it is also showing me error..

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: It is a logical error .....

Comment: Can you paste the code which you have tried.

Comment: I have tried your code

Comment: Your trigger is on before update or before insert? because i can see you are using before update in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85760/in-use-field-restriction-trigger

And in case if a account have 3 contacts out of which one has InUse = true and when you unCheck InUse to false what should be the behavior according to you?

Comment: when you unCheck InUse to false what should be the behavior according to you -- by default it is false. After that if i  do In use=true it will give me error and it is good but when i make in use=false again it didnt give me error message..

Comment: What is the type of your trigger, before insert or before upsert?

Comment: before update...

Comment: can you try by replacing last for loop with below code
for(contact c : trigger.new){
                if(inUseSet.contains(c.AccountId)){
                    if(!(trigger.OldMap.containsKey(c.Id) && trigger.OldMap.get(c.Id).InUse__c))   {
                        c.InUse__c= false;
                    }
                  }
                else{
                    inUseSet.add(c.AccountId);
                }

Comment: It is working fine...

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would be helpful...

```
   trigger validate on Contact(before insert){

        set<id> rids = new set<id>();
        set<id> Uids = new set<id>();

        for(contact c : trigger.new){
              rids.add(c.AccountId);
        }
        list<contact> conts = [select accountid from contact where accountid IN :rids AND In_Use__c = true];
        for(contact c : conts){
           uids.add(c.accountid);
        }

        for(contact c : trigger.new){
             if(uids.contains(c.AccountId)){
                   c.addError('Account Related contact is already in Use');    
             }   

        } 
}
```

Comment: unexpected token: '==' at line 4 column 91 giving this error

Comment: see my updated ans, need to change == to = in query.

Comment: If this is the solution that you wanted..please Mark this ans as a it would be  helpful.... Thanks..

Comment: @AmitChaudhary : Your code has SOQL query inside for loop which is not a good practice.

Comment: @AmitChaudhary: I have a problem that when i am making a new Contact of same account and in use is already active of another contact of same account then also it is showing me error

Comment: Yes that is your requirement.... Please check your question again..

Comment: Yes i checked it is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to fill the requirement without using code:
1. Create a unique field in contact.
2. Create a workflow on creation/update of contact when the in use check box is checked that fills the unique field created in section 1 with the account id.
3. Create a workflow on creation/update of contact when the in use check box is un-checked that clears the unique field created in section 1.
This way, when someone will try to check the in use check box under the same account he will get notification that there's a duplication and referral to the in use contact.

Comment: @Dagnish: But unique field will give me only once checked for all Contacts.For e.g XYZ contact is child of ABC and i checked In use and if i want to check in use of another Parent then it will throw me Workflow error.

Comment: Let's say that the id of account ABC is "ABC" and that the unique field is called "unique in use". On the contact under account ABC with the check box in use checked, the field "unique in use" will have "ABC" in it. If you'll try to check the check box in use for another contact under ABC account, the workflow will set the new contact field "unique in use" to have "ABC" and you will get notification that you have duplicates. If you will check another contact under another account, you will have a different value in the field "unique in use" and you won't have a problem.