# In use Field Restriction Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Hii I have written a trigger which will restrict Field named as "In USE", This trigger is working fine, but when i am going to uncheck "IN USE" and try to save it , it is showing me error.Actually my requirement is only restrict the IN USE field not to show error message while i am changing value of IN USE.

```
trigger validate on Contact(before update){
        SET<String> ids = new SET<String>();
            for(contact c : trigger.new){
                ids.add(c.AccountId);
            } 
            List<AggregateResult> tempAggr = [SELECT AccountId acc FROM Contact WHERE In_Use__c= true AND AccountId IN : ids GROUP BY AccountId];

            Set<String> inUseset = new Set<String>();
            for(AggregateResult rs : tempAggr){
                inUseSet.add(String.valueOf(rs.get('acc')));
            }

            for(contact c : trigger.new){
                if(inUseSet.contains(c.AccountId)){

                    c.adderror('In Use already used by another Contact');
                    c.In_Use__c= false;
                }
                else{


                    inUseSet.add(c.AccountId);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can disable that checkbox field on this particular condition...... What you are using Standard page or visualforce page...?

Comment: I am using Standard Page

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan : I would suggest you to continue this discussion on original thread http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84925/restrict-filed-from-other-childs/84935?noredirect=1#comment112713_84935

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
trigger validate on Contact (before update) {
        SET<String> ids = new SET<String>();
            for(contact c : trigger.new){
                ids.add(c.AccountId);
            }

            List<AggregateResult> tempAggr = [SELECT AccountId acc FROM Contact WHERE InUse__c= true AND AccountId IN : ids GROUP BY AccountId];

            Set<String> inUseset = new Set<String>();
            for(AggregateResult rs : tempAggr){
                inUseSet.add(String.valueOf(rs.get('acc')));
            }
              for(contact c : trigger.new){
                if(inUseSet.contains(c.AccountId)){
                    if(!(trigger.OldMap.containsKey(c.Id) && trigger.OldMap.get(c.Id).InUse__c))   {
                        c.adderror('In Use already used by another Contact');
                        c.InUse__c= false;
                    }
                  }
                else{
                    inUseSet.add(c.AccountId);
                }
            }

}
```